# Adding two numbers without float variable

Tags: floating-point, precision, long-integer, floating-accuracy

i need to write function that add  two numbers but we have a processor that does not support a Variable type  Float !!

So to represent fractions , is using a long integer is represented with actually represented using 4B-32bit.

We define the long bits as follows:

the MSB  marked S -signed .

The 8 bits following marked E - Exponentially.

The remaining 23 bits marked M -mantissa.

The following formula represents the fraction in long:

(E^2)*(M)*(S^-1).

and i need to write the function :

unsigned long add(unsigned long float1, unsigned long float2)

that Receives two long values (which are actually fractions),add them and return the answer in long .

I tried to do something like this but i get stuck .

unsigned long add(unsigned long float1, unsigned long float2) {

```
    char E1=float1>>23, E2=float2>>23, E3;
```

.
.
.
.

thanks :)

Comment: what language/enviriorment?

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase [sui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3199345/3990396), here is some pseudo code.

```
while exponent(f1) > exponent(f2):
    increment exponent(f2)
    shiftleft mantissa(f2)

while exponent(f2) > exponent(f1):
    increment exponent(f1)
    shiftleft mantissa(f1)

add mantissa(f1) to mantissa(f2)
adjust exponent
calculate sign
```